# Solve an ODE $x'' + 186(x')^2 $ = constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Solve the ordinary differential equation $x'' + 186(x')^2$ = constant.

It is an exercise from textbook. I have no idea to solve the ODE. Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a not so obvious substitution set $y=e^{186x}$ then
$$
y''(t)=e^{186x(t)}\,186(x''(t)+186x'(t)^2)=186\,c\,y(t)
$$
which now is a standard linear differential equation of second order.

Answer (score 1):

Hint let $x'=u $ so we have $x''=u' $ the new equation is $u'+186u^2=c $ . Now you can see its variable separable differential equation. $\frac {du}{dx}=c-186u^2$ hence $\int \frac {du}{c-186u^2}=x+d $ . From here we can integrate lhs and then again put $u=x'$ to solve the next differential equation. Note that here $d $ is a constant.

Comment: Sorry let me correct it.

Comment: It's not linear, but it is seperable.

Comment: is this correct ? is $u' = du/dx$ ??

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: please correct your answer